# Using xlsx in Angular - How to make excel identify the dates as actual dates in column automatically?

Tags: excel, angular, npm, xlsx

I have an angular service that creates excel files:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {

  constructor() { }

  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    console.log('worksheet',worksheet);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { data: worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    if(!wb.Workbook) wb.Workbook = {};
    if(!wb.Workbook.Views) wb.Workbook.Views = [];
    if(!wb.Workbook.Views[0]) wb.Workbook.Views[0] = {};
    wb.Workbook.Views[0].RTL = true;
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }

}
```

**The service works** and it creates the file with dates which are **well formatted**, but Excel would only recognize them if I touch them one by one or edit the settings of the entire column.

That's how I activate the service:

```
const temp = this.dataSource.data.map(e => {
  return {
    'id': controlValueIfNull(e.Id),
    'date': '30/06/2020',
    'time': seperateDateFromHour(e.DonationHour, 'GET_HOUR_ONLY'),
  }
});
this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(temp,"Donations");
```

The dates are formatted like that: ***'01/12/2020'*** - they are identified automatically if I just take an excel file and write it down, but when I export it, it doesn't recognize them automatically.

Any thoughts? I would love for some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally solved!**
There's no need to format the date (it fits my country format).
Instead of tempering with and sending string like *'17/02/2020'* it I just put:

```
'column name': new Date(dateChosen)
```

It just worked!
Now filtering by date in Excel exists.